# ¿Cómo puedo sustituir "\" (barra inversa) por "/" (barra)?

Tags: python, replace

Estoy haciendo una función que me facilite el reemplazar la barra inversa () con la que vienen las ubicaciones de los archivos por la barra (/) con la que python lee las ubicaciones.

El problema está en que al usar .replace(), si pongo "" me toma como texto todo lo posterior.

```
def ubica(self):
    return self.replace('\','/')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El caracter "\" es el caracter de escape. SI quieres incluirlo en un texto, tienes que escaparlo, o sea `self.replace('\\', '/')`

Answer (score 0):

### Teoría

El carácter `\` es especial dentro de una cadena python. Sirve para marcar que el siguiente (o siguiente) carácter(s) debe(n) ser interpretado(s) de forma diferente.

Por ejemplo, si dentro de una cadena aparece `"\n"`, eso no significa que la cadena tenga dos caracteres ahí, la barra inversa y la n, sino en realidad un solo caracter que es el de "nueva línea", pues la barra `\` está cambiando el significado del caracter (o caracteres) que van después. Esto es útil para poder meter en cadenas caracteres que de otro modo no podrías meter porque no son imprimibles o porque no están en tu teclado.

Otro ejemplo, la secuencia `\U` sirve para meter en una cadena cualquier carácter del estándar unicode. Así, por ejemplo, si quieres meter un emoji en una cadena pero tu teclado no tiene forma de introducir emojis, basta que averigues el código del emoji que quieres introducir (por ejemplo, el emoji de serpiente es el código 1F40D. En python hay que rellenarlo con ceros por la izquierda hasta completar ocho cifras, por lo que lo podrías meter así:

```
texto = "Python \U0001F40D soporta unicode"
```

A pesar de que para imprimirlo hemos usado una barra inversa, una U y un montón de números, en Python todo eso se reducirá a un sólo caracter: el emoji de serpiente:

```
print(texto)
# Resultado: Python  soporta unicode
```

### Tu problema

De hecho, una `\` delante de un carácter de comillas, hace que Python meta ese carácter (las comillas) dentro de una cadena. Esto puede ser útil en casos como este:

```
dialogo = "Juan dijo \"Hola\""
```

En tu caso es eso lo que está dando problemas ya que `'\'` no es una cadena con el `\` dentro, sino una cadena "sin terminar, puesto que la comilla de cierre no se ha interpretado como tal, sino como un carácter más dentro de la cadena.

### Soluciones

Hay tres soluciones:

1. Escapar el carácter `\` poniendo otro `\` delante. Es decir, escribir `'\\'`. La secuencia `\\` se entiende como un solo `\` a meter en la cadena (el primer `\` avisa a python de que viene una secuencia especial que debe codificarse como un solo carácter, el segundo `\` dice cuál ha de ser el carácter resultante).
2. Usar el código unicode del  `\`, que es el 92, en hexadecimal 5C. De modo que puedes escribir `\U0000005C` para representar la barra inversa. Para códigos Unicode menores de 4 cifras hex puedes usar también la versión "compacta" de solo 4 dígitos, precedidos por `\u` minúscula. Es decir, `\u005c`.
3. La que suele usarse más a menudo, poner una `r` delante de las comillas de apertura para indicar que el carácter `\` no es especial. Así, si en un programa en python aparece la cadena `r"\n"` en este caso la `r` del inicio indica que la cadena es *raw* y que `\` pierde su significado especial, y significa simplemente el carácter barra inversa.

Por desgracia la opción 3 no funciona si `\` aparece justo antes de las comillas de cierre. ¿Un bug? Debido a este problema la solución 3 no es aplicable a tu caso, por lo que la más sencilla sería la solución 1.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> def ubica(self):
>     return self.replace(" \ ".strip(), "/")
> ```

Tal vez esta pueda ser una solución para tu problema.